# How to re open an activity after finishing it and also start the Camera Preview again in it

Tags: android, android-activity, camera, android-camera

In my camera app's Launcher activity named `CameraActivity` I've overridden the `onPause()` method as below,

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mCamera.release();
    finish();
}
```

So that whenever the app is exited by pressing home button or back button the camera gets released and the activity is finished to let other Camera Apps to access the Camera. But now I've  created another activity named `CameraSettings`. And used `Intent` to open it. The problem is when I want to go back to the `CameraActivity` the app closes and returns to the home screen because I've used the `finish()` method in `onPause()`. Even if I don't use `finish()` method, I'd still get error because the camera is already released.

What I want is, when I am in the `CameraActivity` if I press back/home then the camera will get released and if I go to the `CameraSettings` activity, after making changes to camera I want to go back to the `CameraActivity` which will reopen the Camera to use. I tried overriding the `onResume()` method and start the camera preview again but it gives error. Below is the `onResume()` moethod,

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mCamera.startPreview();
}
```

Here's my `onCreate()` method where I started my Camera Preview for the first time,

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_test);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    //ShutterSound
    final Camera.ShutterCallback shutter = new Camera.ShutterCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onShutter() {

        }
    };

    //Settings listener
    settings = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.settings);
    settings.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent openSettings = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),CameraSettings.class);
            startActivity(openSettings);
        }
    });



    //Capture button listener
    captureButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.captureButton);
    captureButton.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    captureButton.setEnabled(false);
                    // get an image from the camera
                    mCamera.takePicture(shutter, null, mPicture);
                }
            }
    );

    //Switch the cameras
    switchCamera = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.switchCamera);
    switchCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            checkFrontCameraInUse = !checkFrontCameraInUse;
            switchCamera.setEnabled(false);
            switchCamera();
        }
    });

    /*
    * Below code is
    * needed to start the camera first time
    * */

    // Create an instance of Camera
    mCamera = CameraInstance.getCameraInstance(0);
    // Create our Preview view and set it as the content of our activity.
    mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera, 0);
    preview = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);

    assert preview != null;
    preview.addView(mPreview);
}
```

Here's the error message,

```
    FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.prohelika.testcamera, PID: 28304
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Camera is being used after Camera.release() was called
    at android.hardware.Camera.setPreviewSurface(Native Method)
    at android.hardware.Camera.setPreviewDisplay(Camera.java:801)
    at com.prohelika.testcamera.CameraPreview.surfaceCreated(CameraPreview.java:36)
    at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:675)
    at android.view.SurfaceView.onWindowVisibilityChanged(SurfaceView.java:273)
    at android.view.View.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(View.java:8998)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1190)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1190)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1190)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1190)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1190)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1190)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1575)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1296)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6602)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:800)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:603)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:572)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:786)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5717)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
```

Forgive me please if my explanation wasn't good.

Comment: you need to add more details, like what you have tried, what is the error your getting, where your starting your camera preview at first.

Comment: Did you use `startActivityForResult(yourSettingsIntent)`? If not, look into the [docs](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html).

Comment: @Anders I've added the onCreate() method where I used the preview for first time

Comment: @Amy no I didn't but wouldn't it still trigger the onPause() method?

Comment: Hmm, you are right, my fault ^^'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have already released your camera resource, you are getting error while calling `startPreview()` method inside your `onResume()` method.

Set `camera` to `null` after you release it.
And also remove `previewCallback` from camera preview

```
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
        mPreview.getHolder().removeCallback(mPreview);
        mCamera.release();
        mCamera = nulll
        finish();
    }
```

Try checking whether camera is `null` and reinitialize your `camera` instance as below inside `onResume()` method:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (mCamera == null) {
        mCamera = getCameraInstance();
    }
    mCamera.startPreview();
}
```

**P.S.** you may have to reinitialize preview in case of `null`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: It is still giving the same error :( Should I add the error message I'm getting?

Comment: I have added it, please check

Comment: check the answer now

Comment: @FarhanFarooqui have you checked the updated answer ?

Comment: sorry I was out having lunch. I've checked it now, it doesn't give an error but doesn't start the preview either

Comment: see i have added a **P.S.** saying you may have to reinitialise the preview

Comment: @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (mCamera == null) {
            mCamera = CameraInstance.getCameraInstance(0);
        }
        mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera, 0);
        mCamera.startPreview();
    }
This is how reinitialized it but still it isn't working